# Web Form User Control Event, needs to be added after page loads

Tags: asp.net

My application consists of a web form that someone may be pulling some information in.   When that occurs, I'm loading a user control more than once, based on content, that has an ImageButton on it.

Since this is being loaded after page is already loaded, how can I get the click events to work properly.  Since click events are required to be set during page_load.

***Example Scenario:***

**Main.aspx**

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:Button ID="clicker" runat="server" Text="Click Me" />
        <asp:PlaceHolder ID="PHwfuc" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="ResponseMessage"></asp:Label>
    </div>
</form>
```

**Main.aspx.cs**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    clicker.Click += new EventHandler(this.ButClick);
}

protected void ButClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    PlaceHolder placeHolder = new PlaceHolder();

    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        WFUC1 test = LoadControl("~/WebFormUserControl/WFUC1.ascx") as WFUC1;
        test.Ident = i;
        placeHolder.Controls.Add(test);
    }

    PHwfuc.Controls.Add(placeHolder);
}
```

**WFUC1.ascx**

```
<asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="DelAddrBtn"></asp:PlaceHolder>
<asp:Label runat="server" ID="ResponseMessage"></asp:Label>
<br />
```

**WFUC1.ascx.cs**

```
public WFUC1()
{
    TrashIcon = new ImageButton
    {
        AlternateText = "Delete Address",
        ImageUrl = "/images/trash.png",
        ToolTip = "Delete Address",
    };

    TrashIcon.Style.Add("cursor", "pointer");
    TrashIcon.Style.Add("width", "24px");
}

private ImageButton TrashIcon { get; set; }

public int Ident { get; set; }

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TrashIcon.ID = $"Delete_{Ident}";
    TrashIcon.Click += new ImageClickEventHandler(this.TrashIcon_Click);
    DelAddrBtn.Controls.Add(TrashIcon);
}

protected void TrashIcon_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
    ResponseMessage.Text = $"Use Control Got it. {Ident}";
}
```

**EDIT For Rango**

**WFUC1.ascx**

```
<asp:ImageButton runat="server" ID="TrashIcon" ImageUrl = "/images/trash.png" ToolTip = "Delete Address" OnClick="TrashIcon_Click" />
<asp:Label runat="server" ID="ResponseMessage"></asp:Label>
<br />
```

**WFUC1.ascx.cs**

```
public partial class WFUC1 : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
    public int Ident { get; set; }

    protected void TrashIcon_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
    {
        ResponseMessage.Text = $"Use Control Got it. {Ident}";
    }
}
```

Comment: This user control is actually an Address Edit screen with input boxes.  The user for this address could have multiple addresses.  On the control, there are  Delete buttons for each address so someone could delete one or more records.   Since it's a large amount of code, I couldn't post it all here, so created this demo.

Comment: I edited the code above, it still doesn't execute the on click event.

Comment: Maybe, I wasn't 100% clear..   I need to dynamically load the User Control, because this person could have more than 1 address of which they are displaying or editing.   Delete needs to be know which one they are clicking delete on.  This is why I can't just Register and display the control.

Comment: Try publishing a code that at least compile. There are duplicate variable names between asp and the code behind so it's unclear which object you're expecting to access.

Comment: Not really..  There is an Edit for Rango between them..   This edit replaces what is above it.   I found the answer now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems, I have to reload all the controls on the main again to get the click event to execute.   I accidentally made this work.

[Below Project Visual Studio 2017](http://www.chizl.com/downloads/WFUCTest.zip) - No binaries, except for one image and the rest is only project code.

**Main.aspx**

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:Button ID="clicker" runat="server" Text="Click Me" />
    <asp:PlaceHolder ID="PHwfuc" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
    <asp:Label runat="server" ID="ResponseMessage"></asp:Label>
</form>
```

**Main.aspx.cs**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    clicker.Click += new EventHandler(this.ButClick);

    if(ViewState["ButClick"] != null)
        LoadData();
}

protected void ButClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    LoadData();
}

private void LoadData()
{
    PlaceHolder placeHolder = new PlaceHolder();

    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        WFUC1 test = LoadControl("~/WebFormUserControl/WFUC1.ascx") as WFUC1;
        test.Ident = i;
        placeHolder.Controls.Add(test);
    }

    PHwfuc.Controls.Add(placeHolder);
    ViewState["ButClick"] = true;
}
```

**WFUC1.ascx**

```
<asp:ImageButton runat="server" ID="TrashIcon" ImageUrl = "/images/trash.png" ToolTip = "Delete Address" OnClick="TrashIcon_Click" />
<br />
<asp:Label runat="server" ID="ResponseMessage"></asp:Label>
```

**WFUC1.ascx**

```
public int Ident { get; set; }

public void TrashIcon_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
    ResponseMessage.Text = $"Use Control Got it. {Ident}";
}
```